# Prime factorization of factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

Is there a way given a sequence of naturals $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k$ to determine whether $c=n!$ for some number $n$ where 
$$ c = 2^{a_1}  3^{a_2}5^{a_3}7^{a_4}...$$ (2,3,5,7,... - primes)

Comment: Use that $n! = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} p^{\sum_{k \ge 1}k\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor}$

Comment: That should depend on the sequence, I think.

Comment: @user1952009 but if I use the formula on 8! I get $2^{11}*3^2*5*7=645120$ but $8! = 40320$

Comment: @tmac_balla $8! = 2^{4+2+1} 3^2 5^1 7^1$

Comment: Two users upvoted this question (which happens to be no more than one sentence.)  No context provide (why are you asking this? where did this question arise for you? Have you done any work on you own to explore this problem, and if so, please share, and if not, sorry, but we aren't a homework-completion site.  It's typical, unfortunately, that someone who actually answers such a question, and hence has vested interest in it, will upvote the question s/he answered.  But, for the other: Having the privilege of upvoting/downvoting, it is also expected that you vote responsibly.

Comment: @amWhy : come on

Comment: @user1952009,  I'm not in the mood, thankyou.  Of course,  it's your choice to enable folks to put no work, themselves, to answer a question.  Just sayin'....  Unfortunately you may unwittingly be lowering  the quality of this site when turn around and answer such a question. Just sayin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n! = \prod_p p^{\sum_{k \ge 1} k \lfloor n/p^k\rfloor}$$

- You are given a prime decomposition $A  =\prod_p p^{a_p}$ and you want to know if it exists $r$ such that $r! = \prod_p p^{a_p}$. Of course you can compute $A$ and use the dichotomy for finding $r$.
- Otherwise, note that if  $n$ is even then it is fully determinated by $a_2 = \sum_{k \ge 1} k \lfloor n/2^k\rfloor$.

  So you can make use only of $a_2$ for finding (if it exists, using dichotomy) $n$ even such that $a_2 = \sum_{k \ge 1} k \lfloor n/2^k\rfloor$.
- Then look at the other exponents for choosing if the correct result is $r = n$ or $r=n+1$, or if $A$ is not a factorial

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Let $a_k ≥ 1$ be the last element of the series, let q be the k-th prime and r the (k+1)st prime, then q ≤ n < r. (If n < q then there's no factor q so $a_k = 0$, if n ≥ r then there's a factor r so $a_{k+1} ≥ 1$).

You can check quite easily how often a prime p is prime factor of n!. For example, 133! is the product of 133 numbers. 26 are divisible by 5, 5 are divisible by $5^2$, one is divisible by $5^3$, so 133! has a factor $5^{32}$. So for each prime p ≤ 1 you check which power of p is a factor of q! and (r-1)!. If the corresponding $a_i$ is too small for q! or too large for (r-1)! then you haven't got a factorial. Otherwise you may be able to limit the range of n.